# mysql data free always zero(0)

Tags: mysql, jsp, workbench

I am using mysql workbench for mysql databases.
I created 2 tables to store files.i.e., "database" and "reports".
I used the same collation and engine for both tables.
But when I look in the table maintenance, "data free" for table-database is always 1Mib
but for table-reports is always 0.

Consequently when I try to download the file from the database, it downloads just 10bytes. I am quite sure my code to download file from the database is correct, since I am using the same code for the table-database, and its working perfectly, and not with table-reports (I know that for table-reports I need to change some parameters and field names).

Kindly solve the issue.

Comment: correction - "Consequently when i try to download the file from the table-reports, it downloads just 10bytes.

Comment: PS  - to avoid confusion ,tables are = "database" and "reports".